# Javascript chrome extension doesn't work in new tab

Tags: javascript

I have a chrome extension made in Javascript. The code works fine up until the code below, where I programatically open a new tab and try to interact with the new page, it gives the error:

> `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

I tried it manually in the the browser console and it works.

content.js:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus;
document.getElementById('single_custom_css').innerHTML="123";
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "name":"Automate",
    "version":"1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["thesite.com"],
            "js":["content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That means you don't have an HTML element in your DOM with the ID of `single_custom_css` once running that JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi, the command works fine when I run it in the console. I think the issue is that i've opened a new page, maybe it's still looking at the code from the original page?

Comment: @BradleyJoe that is what is happening, you need to focus on the new tab to be able to interact with the DOM.

Comment: That's why I use win.focus;